# Issue with stacking in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

I'm trying to stack my dataset using PANDAS and set the countries as the index.

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cleibowitz/Module-6/main/Module%206%20Dataset%20-%20GDP%20TRANSPOSED.csv'

data = pd.read_csv(url, index_col = 'Year')

data.columns.name = 'Country'

data = pd.DataFrame(data.stack().rename('value'))

data.reset_index()

data = data.query('Year == 2020')


data.set_index('Country')

data
```

For some reason, I keep getting this error that it can't find "Country", yet I know it is in the dataset. I'm looking for this output:[image: output]

Would someone mind helping me with this? Thanks!

Comment: It already index , also , data.index.name = 'Country'

Comment: Change the 6th line of code to `data = data.reset_index()`

Answer (score 0):

You must reset your index before (because index is the group of year and country) :

```
data.reset_index().set_index('Country')
```